# Flask html table truncating contents

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I have a html page with a table inside it, and I am showing a pandas dataframe in it.

Python code is:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, redirect
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


app = Flask(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c--', 'd', 'e']})


@app.route('/', methods=("POST", "GET"))
def html_table():

    return render_template('simple.html',  tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

The html for the table is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% for table in tables %}
            {{titles[loop.index]}}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

In some instances, when a column contents are large the displayed table truncates the contents.

How do I work around this problem by forcing the table to show all pulled contents?

Comment: What does truncate mean? Is the text present in the source or just not visible in the browser? If its truncated with `...` and present in the source then most likely you have some `text-overflow: ellipsis` styling anywhere.

Comment: @CodeSpirit, the text is present in the source and just not visible in the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to reconstruct this. I've replaced the following line `'C': ['a'*1000, 'b', 'c--', 'd', 'e']` but I get the value `a` a thousand times in my browser without any truncation (counted in Sublime). I'm using the code and `simple.html` template you provided above. Perhaps it's your browser settings, so try it in a different browser?

Comment: @napoleon_borntoparty, that is very strange. I tried with another browser and got same results. Do you mind trying with this sample text in the column C: ```Nov 3, 2019 - The average hours worked for a Chief Executive Officer (CEO) ... Skills in Leadership and Business Strategy are correlated to hours that is ...' ```